# Why is temp used here and not vtx( in line 3)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This code is used to `enqueue` at the front end:

```
Vertex vtx = new Vertex(v)

vtx.next = head

if (head != null) head.prev = temp

head = vtx
```

Comment: There is some code missing. Where is `temp` declared / assigned? It should be `head.prev = vtx`

Comment: please check this out https://visualgo.net/en/list